# Android Studio could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+

Tags: android, android-appcompat

New to Android Studio. After setting everything up I tried to run a basic project and keep getting this error. I changed my appcompat version to 7.22.+ and it builds. Can anyone explain this? I know I'm supposed to download that version but from where? Thank you!

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+.
>        Versions that do not match:
>            22.2.1
>            22.2.0
>            22.1.0
>            22.0.0
>            21.0.3
>            + 7 more
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
>            file:/Users/liyicky/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/Users/liyicky/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
>            file:/Users/liyicky/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
>        Required by:
>            RayWenderlichTutorial:app:unspecified

Comment: Today is a bad day to start in on Android, as a new SDK and such were released. `appcompat-v7` v23 is not out yet AFAICT, despite Google's blog to the contrary, and Android Studio is probably somewhat confused as a result.

Comment: When in doubt check your Android SDK manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been dealing with this too. It looks like they updated Android Studio to use appcompat v7:23 as a default even though it hasn't been released yet.

Comment: Not my -1 but probably because confirming the nature of the problem is better done in comments.

Answer (score 9):

Change all the dependencies with the package name `com.android.support:` version from `23` to `22.2.1` or `22.+` then sync Gradle.

This will fix it till they update the support libraries.

Example

```
dependencies {
    // compile `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+`
    compile `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1`
}
```

**Update August 18th, 2015: couple hours later**

Android Support 23 is available now. You can now restore your dependencies back as they were before and download the two below using the Android Studio SDK manager:

**Support Repository 17**

**Android Support Library 23.0.0**

Comment: If you're on OSX look under ~/Library/Android/sdk/sources and see if you have android-23

Comment: @Exeon Thanks for the update--oddly enough when I re-opened a version controlled version of my original project I got this error after restarting the studio (and to my knowledge everything was up to date). I just kept allowing the sdk manager to update what it said it needed and eventually it took. Kinda weird. 2015-10-07 v7:23.0.0

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Just with `implementation` instead of `compile`: `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'` and then `Try again` at the top of the window to sync Gradle. And it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have downloaded ***Android Support Repository*** (not only *Android Support Library*) - launch the SDK Manager (from your android-sdk location, on Windows must be as administrator, otherwise it might not connect) and look in the *Extras* section if you have both these components installed (I'm assuming you already have the Android SDK of the desired API level). Restart your IDE and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it by changing the dependency on build.gradle to

'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
}
```

Also, lower the targetSKVersion from 23 to 22 as shown

targetSdkVersion 22

and compileSDKVersion from 23 to 22

compileSdkVersion 22

I hope have solved your issue

Also you can solve the problem by upgrading to the current visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have installed the API 22 at least. 
[image]